# When to use callbacks vs just returning a value

Tags: ruby, callback

I was looking at some Ruby code somewhere, and I saw the following line:

```
def do_something a, b, c, &callback
  xyz = a + b + c
  callback.call(xyz)
end
```

and then when it was called, they did something like this:

```
do_something a, b, c do |xyz|
  puts xyz
end
```

Is this better practice to use this sort of callback as opposed to just returning the value made by the function? I can understand why it would be done if there are multiple values that need to be transferred, but this one has just one return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Analysis

There is insufficient information in your original post to determine if this is *useful* or not. The intent of your first example seems to be that the method will be passed a block, which is then called as a Proc inside the method rather than yielded back to the block. There might be a valid use case for this, but your given example isn't one of them.

If the block is already there, why not just yield to the block? And what happens if no block is given?

Passing Proc or lambda objects around can certainly be a useful technique in certain cases, but unless it simplifies your code or makes it more readable you are creating additional complexity. The examples in your original post don't make a valid case for why it might be needed. Even if you update your post with better examples, "Is a Proc object necessary?" is almost certainly a subjective question based on the needs of the larger program.

Unless you need the features of a Proc or lambda (e.g. you need a closure or access to a specific [Binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Binding.html)) then you are *generally* better off yielding to a block or returning a value. Your mileage may certainly vary.

### Yield or Return

In the general case, you can choose to yield to a block or return a value depending on whether or not a block was given. For example:

```
def do_something(a, b, c)
  xyz = a + b + c
  block_given? ? yield(xyz) : xyz
end
```

Unless you need to pass around a closure, this is likely to be a more useful technique. However, as previously stated, your mileage (and code base) may vary.

Answer (score 2):

I would call this bad practice since this method *requires* a block (you'll get a `NoMethodError` without one). It can be useful to have a mechanism for immediately passing the return value to a block, but I wouldn't make it mandatory.

A simple improvement would be to make the block optional

```
def do_something a, b, c
  xyz = a + b + c
  return yield(xyz) if block_given?
  xyz
end
```